# Does Apache Flink RichAsyncFunction open() get called once on init or per function call?

Tags: apache-flink

Does the open() function get executed once on init or every time the rich function executes?

So, if we wants to execute a heavy operation like creating a Database DataSource, we can do it there and it won't be inited on each call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `open()` method is called once during operator initialization, for each parallel instance of the operator. So yes, this is where you'd do the "heavy" one-time initialization calls.

Comment: Ok from my testing it seems to work. I only have one node now. So I guess when the job gets executed/split on multiple agents. The open() will be called once for each node correct?

Comment: There's one open call per **instance** of the operator. The parallelism of that operator (not the number of nodes) determines how many instances you've got.

Comment: Ah ok. So setParallelism(...). Cool!

Comment: @kkrugler I have initialization of custom metric in open method of a class that implements KafkaDeserializationSchema and then it throws a NPE in the deserialize method. How is possible deserialize method to be called before open?

Comment: Just found the solution - there were bug in Flink 1.11.0 which is resolved in 1.11.3. Open method in basekafkaconsumer was called in else statement instead outside of it.